# LibVirt (QEMU) Shutting down from inside guest

Tags: debian, libvirt, qemu, guest, acpi

I am currently running LibVirt with Qemu on Debian Wheezy:

Versions:

- libvirtd (libvirt) 1.2.4
- qemu-x86_64 version 2.0.0 (Debian 2.0.0+dfsg-4~bpo70+1), Copyright (c) 2003-2008 Fabrice Bellard

It's all working perfectly, including ACPI: virsh shutdown guest. However when I issue "halt" from the guest, the guest stops but libvirt thinks it is still running: (virsh list outputs state: running).
virsh dominfo does the same thing: State:          running

I believe this is due to the -no-shutdown flag passed to qemu, making it stop the CPUs rather than halt entirely. Is this however a bug that the status is not updated correctly?

Comment: Strangely enough it works perfectly fine on Ubuntu :( Not sure how I can look for the issue, since I've got Debian installed on this server.

Answer (score 1):

The 'halt' command just halts the CPUs - if you want to actually turn off the machine, you need the 'poweroff' command instead. The latter is what 'virsh shutdown' would ultimately trigger.